# How to manipulate the 2d array to get the data's in column vice instead of row vice using for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

The Below code process the data like this a[0][0],a[0][1],a[0][2] but i wanted it like a[0][0],a[1][0],a[2][0]

```
for (var i = 0; i < args.chart.data.length;i++){                            
       for (var j = 0; j < args.chart.data[i].length; j++) {                                
                    content = args.chart.data[i][j] ; 
                }        
}
```

I wanted to fetch the data from the array like the example given below. 
For Eg:

```
    a[0][0],
    a[1][0],
    a[2][0],
//and then 
    a[0][1],
    a[1][1],
    a[2][1],
```

This is my data
      [[Jira Training, Sum], [1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 4]]

The below is my code.

```
for (var i = 0; i < args.chart.data.length; i++)         {                          
for (var j = 0; j < args.chart.data[i].length; j++) {
console.log("J : "+ j+ " i : "+ i +"     "+args.chart.data[j][i]);                  
  }                       
}
```

The output is below, which gives undefined for some data.

```
J : 0 i : 0 Jira Training
J : 1 i : 0 1
J : 0 i : 1 Sum
J : 1 i : 1 1
J : 0 i : 2 undefined
J : 1 i : 2 undefined
J : 0 i : 3 undefined
J : 1 i : 3 undefined
J : 0 i : 4 undefined
J : 1 i : 4 undefined
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you could tell us what programming language you're using. Please edit your question to add the appropriate tag. Also please tell us what you mean by "fetch the data". What data? Fetch from where? What are you going to do with this data? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I am using javascript.

Comment: Have you tried just swapping `i` and `j` on the third line of your code? EDIT: This assumes you do not have a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

Comment: I tried swapping, but it didn't work

Comment: This is my data
[[Jira Training, Sum], [1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 4]]
The below is my code,
for (var i = 0; i < args.chart.data.length; i++) {                     
  for (var j = 0; j < args.chart.data[i].length; j++) {
     console.log("J : "+ j+ " i : "+ i +" "+args.chart.data[j][i]);               
  }                   
}
The output is below, which gives undefined.
J : 0 i : 0 Jira Training
J : 1 i : 0 1
J : 0 i : 1 Sum
J : 1 i : 1 1
J : 0 i : 2 undefined
J : 1 i : 2 undefined
J : 0 i : 3 undefined
J : 1 i : 3 undefined
J : 0 i : 4 undefined
J : 1 i : 4 undefined